# Xcode: breakpoints in the C++ headers files seems to be ignored

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, xcode4, breakpoints

I'm running in Xcode 4.3.3 an iOS project with some C++ classes.

When I run it in debug mode the breakpoints in the C++ headers files seem to be ignored. For example, the barcode on the third line of this code doesn't work:

```
    class myClass : public Reader {
    private:
        static const int INTEGER_MATH_SHIFT = 8;
```

I'm expecting the code to break on the constant assignment, or am I wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A breakpoint can only be set on executable code.  The initialization of an object with static lifetime with a constant expression doesn't generate any executable code (and while you mention assignment, there's no assignment in the code you've posted).  In fact, in the special case of a constant of integral type, it's likely that the object doesn't exist at all unless you take its address.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say there is not assignment ? I thought I'm using the assignment operator "="

Comment: There's no assignment operator in your code.  In a declaration, the `=` sign is not an operator, but simply part of the grammar, and it doesn't mean assignment, but simply indicates that an initialization expression will follow (for copy initialization).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, breakpoints can be set only on command lines not on assignments. If you set breakpoint on assignment in implementation file it will stop on next operator line

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on an assignment; I do it all the time.  But there's no assignment in his code.

Comment: @JamesKanze Why do you say there is not assignment ? I thought I'm using the assignment operator "=".